# Move the objects on the plane when certain object move towords it

Tags: java, math, geometry, distance

I have set of stars(places) with their distance from point **P**. and I can move point **P** also.

Now I want to put that stars on the graph according to the distance from that point **P**. such that star with small distance is closer to the point **P** and its diameter large than other and star with larger distance is far away from point **P**.

when the point **P** moves towards the stars the closest star will be bigger and bigger then move away also other stars also come closer. so I want to first put the stars in such a way that star with smaller distance near to point P than larger distance and when I move object **P** the points come closer with increased diameter and move away. so how I can Implement that.

Comment: Are you talking about parallax? http://www.david-gouveia.com/2d-camera-with-parallax-scrolling-in-xna/

Comment: thanks.. yes the same effect I want with gwt..